# iOS Google AdMob + AppLovin - Other Linker Flags?

Tags: ios, admob, applovin

I try to integrate Admob and AppLovin Framework together in my iOS project.

AppLovin needs "Other Linker Flag" -ObjC, but in Admob it produces an error:

```
174 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

How can I handle that, that AppLovin needs Other Linker Flag, but AdMob not?

Answer (score 0):

I got that. -force_load did the job

> -force_load $(SRCROOT)/MyFolder/libAppLovinSdk.a